# Seemingly Random Timeouts using Packer with Ansible on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, packer

I am baking AWS AMIs using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) and [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).  It seems that after about 6 minutes or so of Packer running, the process will fail.  Aside from it taking about 6 minutes, I can't seem to find a logical explanation as to what is happening.  The Ansbile playbook will fail at different points along the way but always about 6 minutes after I launch Packer.

I always get an Ansible error when I hit this issue.  I either get `Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:` or `Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n`

Is there a way to extend the timeouts associated with a playbook or Packer builder?

Packer file contents:

```
{
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "ansible",
    "playbook_file": "../ansible/nexus.yml"
  }],

  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-ebs",
    "region": "us-east-2",
    "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "name": "amzn-ami-hvm*-gp2",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners": ["137112412989"],
        "most_recent": true
    },
    "instance_type": "t2.medium",
    "ami_virtualization_type": "hvm",
    "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
    "ami_name": "Nexus (Latest Amazon Linux Base) {{isotime \"2006-01-02T15-04-05-06Z\"| clean_ami_name}}",
    "ami_description": "Nexus AMI",
    "run_tags": {
        "AmiName": "Nexus",
        "AmiCreatedBy": "Packer"
    },
    "tags": {
        "Name": "Nexus",
        "CreatedBy": "Packer"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: This is not a Packer problem, but a Ansible problem. Could you add your playbook and maybe rerun with `"extra_arguments": [ "-vvv" ]` to get more debug output from Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue adding following parameters at Ansible configuration file:

```
[defaults]
forks = 1

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none -o ControlPersist=no
pipelining = false
```

Hope it helps.